# How to execute same test multiple times for different dataset using TestNG

Tags: testng

I have a test method 
for example

```
@Test
public void add(){
number1=number2+number3;
}
```

and i have external data like

a=1  b=2

a=4  b=6

a=7  b=10

i want to execute my @Test method 3 times for different data set.

How to achieve this using testNG framework

Answer (score 1):

You should use DataProviders and write something like this

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@DataProvider(name = "rangeWith2DArray")
    public Object[][] rangeCalculator() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 6, 10},
                {7, 10, 18}
        };
    }

    /**
     * Here 2 Numbers are added
     * And The test runs three times.
     *
     * @param num1     Num1
     * @param num2     Num2
     * @param validate - Number to Validate against
     */
    @Test(dataProvider = "rangeWith2DArray")
    public void testRangeSum(int num1, int num2, int validate) {
        Assert.assertEquals(num1 + num2, validate);
    }
```

The test will run three times and the last one would fail because 7+10 is not 18 :)

Answer (score 1):

By using @Factory and @DataProvider annotation of TestNG you can execute same test-case multiple times with different data.

Please find following code snippet for this.

```
public class ProcessTest implements ITest {

protected ProcessData processData;

@Test
public void executeServiceTest() {
    System.out.println(this.processData.toString());
}

@Factory(dataProvider = "processDataList")
public RiskServiceTest(ProcessData processData) {
    this.processData = processData;
}

@DataProvider(name = "processDataList", parallel=true)
public static Object[] getProcessDataList() {

    Object[] serviceProcessDataList = new Object[10];

for(int i=0; i<=serviceProcessDataList.length; i++){
    ProcessData processData = new ProcessData();
    serviceProcessDataList[i] = processData
}


    return serviceProcessDataList;
}

@Override
public String getTestName() {

    return this.processData.getName();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters or DataProviders (depending on where you want set data) are for you: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters